# html table border always appears in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I am rendering a html table using javascript & jQuery. The aim is to show a colored box (table with colored td) if there is a color supplied by parameter. If not then show nothing (so i am showing empty table with  ). But for both these cases I do not want to show any border. I want a flat color box / empty white box.

```
if (colors == null || colors == '') {
    return '<table border="0" style="none" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>'
}
```

In IE 6 and 7 I can see boxes with no border, but in IE 8 it always shows a border to these table td's even if I mention Border="0". It looks like a 3d cell.

Is there any alternative for IE8? Same code works fine in other versions.

Answer (score 2):

This does not look very healthy. You should not use `border="0"`. `style="none"` is really myterious, since CSS is meant to be inside. `none` is not valid CSS, since CSS-properties are specified in key/value-pairs. I recommend this:

```
<table style="border:0px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
```

You should consider to extract your CSS into external files. Be unobstrusive.

Comment: I tried with "border:0px;" but still it shows border in IE8 I also tried in Firefox and same thing happens there as well. It works in compatibility mode though!

Comment: @Anil: I cannot reproduce that. What is your doctype?

Comment: I use master page. and the above code is in content placeholder of aspx page. And yes, I am using C#.Net 3.5 MVC project.

This is the doc type of master page.

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Answer (score 1):

Per elusive's comment, "You should consider to extract your CSS into external files", I'd try adding a class on the table and setting border styles in an external stylesheet.

```
<table class='no-border' ...><tr><td>&nbsp;</td</tr></table>
```

And in the style sheet:

```
.no-border, .no-border td { border:none; }
```

The `.no-border td` might be the rule you need to solve the problem you're seeing, if the border is being set on a single cell and not the whole table.

(If you want to try it inline first, try `<td style="border:none;"></td>`.)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML appear to be improper. You can do it either with HTML markup or with CSS.

HTML

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
```

CSS

```
<table style="border: 0; padding: 0" cellspacing="3">
```